# Is there a PPA for gvim > 7.4.338?

Tags: ppa, vim

The `breakindent` feature is the greatest thing ever, but it's in 7.4.338. The latest version in the Ubuntu repos is just 7.4, I think. I notice [Arch has a package for it](https://www.archlinux.org/packages/extra/x86_64/gvim/), but I can't seem to find one for Ubuntu yet. I'm hopeless with compiling things, otherwise I'd compile it myself.

Comment: In case you do end up compiling: https://github.com/Valloric/YouCompleteMe/wiki/Building-Vim-from-source

Answer (score 8, accepted):

There is the [pi-rho/dev](https://launchpad.net/~pi-rho/+archive/ubuntu/dev) PPA, 
which has [up-to-date vim packages](https://launchpad.net/~pi-rho/+archive/ubuntu/dev/+packages?field.name_filter=vim&field.status_filter=published&field.series_filter=trusty).

(The current default version for trusty is 8.0.0134.)

The PPA is available for currently supported releases.

Answer (score 5):

Vim 8.0 (just released, 2016-09-12) can be installed from a PPA in Ubuntu 14.04 and 16.04.

```
sudo add-apt-repository ppa:jonathonf/vim
sudo apt-get update
sudo apt-get install vim
```

Answer (score 3):

Today I found this one

```
ppa:pkg-vim/vim-daily
```

It uses the new dailybuild function from launchpad to automatically grab the upstream source and build if there has been a change. So nearly no maintenance needed from ubuntu side.